# Сохранение фона изображения

Tags: php, изображения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сохранить фон изображения? А то после изменения размера фон черный! С `GD` начал работать пару дней назад.

```
<?php
    define("UPLOAD_DIR","upload/");
    define("TEMP_DIR",$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    define("WIDTH",300);
    define("HEIGHT",200);

    if(!empty($_FILES) && $_FILES["image"]["error"] == 0){
        $uploaded = move_uploaded_file(TEMP_DIR,UPLOAD_DIR.$_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    }

    $originalImage = UPLOAD_DIR.$_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $createJpeg    = imagecreatefromjpeg($originalImage);
    $imageSize     = getimagesize($originalImage);
    $imageHeight   = $imageSize[1];
    $imageWidth    = $imageSize[0];

    //Проверка высоты и ширины изображения
    if($imageHeight>HEIGHT && $imageWidth>WIDTH){
        $newHeight = HEIGHT;
        $newWidth  = WIDTH;

        $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth,$newHeight);
        imagejpeg($newImage,$originalImage,100);  
    }
?>
```

Comment: А что Вы хотите сделать? Читаете файл, если новые размеры больше старых создаёте пустое новое со старыми размерами и (пустое) сохраняете. Я угадал?

Comment: Читаю если ширина или высота превышает норму,задаю новую ширину и высоту и сохраняю уже с новыми параметрами

Comment: Спасибо щас попрбую!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пустое изображение сохраняете? (Нигде никакой связи со старым jpg не прослеживается.)

Посмотрите imagecopyresampled.

Comment: Все получилось,большое спасибо!

Comment: @Женька Сидоров, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).